# sms send as well as save in sent box

Tags: android, sms, filenotfoundexception

I have developed a sms app in android. I want to save sms when it is sent to a number from sent folder. But it is throwing `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

```
mPhoneNumber = FriendData.getNumber();
    mMessage=messagetosend.getText().toString();
    SmsManager smManager=SmsManager.getDefault();

    ArrayList<String> parts = smManager.divideMessage(mMessage);

    smManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(mPhoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);

    //String userInput = messagetosend.getText().toString();


    try
    {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 

        values.put("address", mPhoneNumber); 

        values.put("body", mMessage);
        values.put("date",  DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
        getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
        //Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
        //InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stream.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SenderMessages(mMessage, c.getTimeInMillis());
        messagetosend.setText("");
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //  finish();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();




     }
```

and exception is

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: No files supported by provider at content://sms/125
```

Comment: Have you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" /> to manifest file?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

Comment: I already set the permission problem is this how we save send message into our sent floder sms is successfully sent